# How do I send an email with an invitation created by a discord bot in python for a maximum amount of uses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've created that bot and I want to make it send invitation for my association's discord channel towards the members that want to join for a limited number of people. There is my code and I hope you can help me figure out why it can't send the email. There is the error I get:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

```
import discord
import random
import smtplib

from email.message import EmailMessage
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

welcome_channel_id = 783308696192811048

@bot.command()
async def inv(ctx, a:int, email:str):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    invlink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age= 300,max_uses = a, temporary = False)
    msg.set_content(f'Hello,\nHere are the invites for the fake discord server{invlink} for a total of {a} uses\n Have a great day,\n faker!')
    msg['Subject'] = 'Invites for discord'
    msg['From'] = 'fake@email.com'
    msg['To'] = email
    s=smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()
    return
```

Comment: Provide a stack trace. After reading the error message, what do you think the problem is?

Comment: 30 seconds with a search engine would have answered your question. Please do not post before doing minimal research first.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the error says, `localhost` (your computer) isn't accepting requests using SMTP. It is likely that the port is closed.

[Open a port (Linux)](https://www.journaldev.com/34113/opening-a-port-on-linux)
[Open a port (Windows)](https://windowsreport.com/open-firewall-ports/)